# Do-While loop error

Tags: java

```
String clientName; 
do
{  
    System.out.println("Enter your Name");
    while (keyboard.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("That's not a name!");
        keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your Name");
    }
    clientName = keyboard.nextLine();

} while (clientName.equals(""));
```

Any idea why this code comes up with "illegal start of type", I'm pulling my hair out.

EDIT: [ALL MY CODE AS REQUESTED](http://pastebin.com/BXCZU3S7)

Comment: (1) post all the code (unless *that is* all the code, in which case you are missing the class definition among other things) (2) tell us what line is giving a compile error.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is that this code is not inside a >>method<<

Comment: I've edited my main post.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653625/java-illegal-start-of-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see here is that you have not initialized the `clientName` String. You should initialize it with `""` .

Here is a corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String clientName = "";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {  
        System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
        while (keyboard.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("That's not a name!");
            keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
        }
        clientName = keyboard.nextLine();
    } while (clientName.equals(""));
}
```

Comment: *"You should initialize it with `""`"*. And why should he do that? Where do you see the improvement? *"You should be using `Scanner` to get the input from `System.in`."* And what do you think is `keyboard` in his code? Or other: why do you think it isn't already a `scanner`?

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your response. I have asked him to initialize it with `""` because he is later checking `clientName.equals("")`. If we don't initialize it then it will throw a compiler error. Sorry I haven't realized that `keyboard` is nothing but Scanner. Updated the solution.

Comment: He initializes that variable inside of the do/while loop, so it will be assigned to an value if it reaches the check in the 'while' part. But you're generally right, one needs to initializes his variable, or he will get a compiler error.

Comment: Btw interesting is that you write "the only issue I see here" and that isn't the issue, but you fixed OPs problem in your example ;P. The problem here is that OP wrote his code on the class level and not inside a method like you correctly did here.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your response. I didn't even realize that! ;P